# Async before and after for creating and dropping scala slick tables in scalatest

Tags: scala, slick, scalatest, slick-3.0

I'm trying to figure out a way to have async `before` and `after` statements where the next test cases aren't run until the completion of the action inside of the test case. In my case, it is the creating and dropping a table inside of a database

```
  val table = TableQuery[BlockHeaderTable]
  val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[PostgresDriver] = DatabaseConfig.forConfig("databaseUrl")
  val database: Database = dbConfig.db
  before {
    //Awaits need to be used to make sure this is fully executed before the next test case starts
    //TODO: Figure out a way to make this asynchronous 
    Await.result(database.run(table.schema.create), 10.seconds)
  }

  "BlockHeaderDAO" must "store a blockheader in the database, then read it from the database" in {
    //...
  }

  it must "delete a block header in the database" in {
    //...
  }

  after {
    //Awaits need to be used to make sure this is fully executed before the next test case starts
    //TODO: Figure out a way to make this asynchronous
    Await.result(database.run(table.schema.drop),10.seconds)
  }
```

Is there a simple way I can remove these `Await` calls inside of my `before` and `after` functions?

Comment: Question: what would be the point of making these asynchronous? If I'm understanding this correctly, you won't be able to run either the `before` or `after` method concurrently with any test or with each other. So even if you find some way of avoiding `Await`, under the hood the system is going to have to wait until the database operation has completed before it can do anything else, or?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, @Jeffrey Chung's solution hanged for me (since `futureValue` actually awaits internally). This is what I ended up doing:

```scala
import org.scalatest.{AsyncFreeSpec, FutureOutcome}
import scala.concurrent.Future

class TestTest extends AsyncFreeSpec /* Could be any AsyncSpec. */ {
  // Do whatever setup you need here.
  def setup(): Future[_] = ???
  // Cleanup whatever you need here.
  def tearDown(): Future[_] = ???
  override def withFixture(test: NoArgAsyncTest) = new FutureOutcome(for {
    _ <- setup()
    result <- super.withFixture(test).toFuture
    _ <- tearDown()
  } yield result)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following is the testing approach that Dennis Vriend takes in his [slick-3.2.0-test](https://github.com/dnvriend/slick-3.2.0-test) project.

First, define a `dropCreateSchema` method. This method attempts to create a table; if that attempt fails (because, for example, the table already exists), it drops, then creates, the table:

```
def dropCreateSchema: Future[Unit] = {
  val schema = BlockHeaderTable.schema
  db.run(schema.create)
    .recoverWith {
      case t: Throwable =>
        db.run(DBIO.seq(schema.drop, schema.create))
    }
}
```

Second, define a `createEntries` method that populates the table with some sample data for use in each test case:

```
def createEntries: Future[Unit] = {
  val setup = DBIO.seq(
    // insert some rows
    BlockHeaderTable ++= Seq(
      BlockHeaderTableRow(/* ... */),
      // ...
    )
  ).transactionally
  db.run(setup)
}
```

Third, define an `initialize` method that calls the above two methods sequentially:

```
def initialize: Future[Unit] = for {
  _ <- dropCreateSchema
  _ <- createEntries
} yield ()
```

In the test class, mix in the [`ScalaFutures`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1-2.12/org/scalatest/concurrent/ScalaFutures.html) trait. For example:

```
class TestSpec extends FlatSpec
  with Matchers
  with ScalaFutures
  with BeforeAndAfterAll
  with BeforeAndAfterEach {

  // ...
}
```

Also in the test class, define an implicit conversion from a `Future` to a `Try`, and override the `beforeEach` method to call `initialize`:

```
implicit val timeout: Timeout = 10.seconds

implicit class PimpedFuture[T](self: Future[T]) {
  def toTry: Try[T] = Try(self.futureValue)
}

override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
  blockHeaderRepo.initialize // in this example, initialize is defined in a repo class
    .toTry recover {
      case t: Throwable =>
        log.error("Could not initialize the database", t)
    } should be a 'success
}

override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
  db.close()
}
```

With the above pieces in place, there is no need for `Await`.

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify @Jeffrey Chung

A simplified `dropCreateSchema` method:

```
def dropCreateSchema: Future[Unit] = {
  val schema = users.schema
  db.run(DBIO.seq(schema.dropIfExists, schema.create))
}
```

Also in the test class, I simplified `beforeEach` method that calls `initialize`. I removed an implicit conversion from a `Future` to a `Try`, and use `onComplete` callback:

```
  override protected def beforeEach(): Unit = {
    initialize.onComplete(f => 
      f recover {
        case t: Throwable =>
          log.error("Could not initialize the database", t)
      } should be a 'success)
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    db.close()
  }
```

Comment: onComplete doesn't ensure that the future finishes before `beforeEach` returns. You have a race condition.